# LinkedHashSet iteration not in ascending order?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, linkedhashset

In the following code, if the parameter is {1,3,2}, in the while loop, i is 1, 3, 2.

I am already using LinkedHashSet, why is the order not 1, 2, 3?  What else do I need to do to make the iteration in ascending order?

Cannot use `TreeSet` as it `add, remove, contains()` in o(log n) time.

```
public static void iterate(int[] num) {
    LinkedHashSet<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i : num) {
        set.add(i);
    }

    Iterator<Integer> iter = set.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        // WHY IS i THE SAME ORDER AS INSERATION ORDER, NOT ASSENDING ORDER?
        int i = iter.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because a LinkedHashSet iterates in insertion order and is not sorted!

Comment: You should you TreeSet if you want to get it ordered.

Comment: TreeSet.contains()'s complexity is o(logn), but I want to o(1).

Comment: For which operations do you want constant complexity?

Comment: I hope to get add() to be o(1)

Comment: So add() and contains() should be constant? And the elements should be ordered by a comparator/natural ordering?

Comment: Yes, that's my expectations when I use a hash.  ascending order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a LinkedHashSet iterates in insertion order and is not sorted! From the javadoc:

*This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).*

You will want to use TreeSet for a sorted set, have a look at the sorted set javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

Comment: TreeSet.contains()'s complexity is o(logn), but I want to o(1).

Comment: Well that is another question entirely :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want a HashSet for a fast `contains` and rightly saw that LinkedHashSet maintains an extra data structure, unfortunately for ordering by insertion.

If the above code shows *all* insertions, you could sort the inserted data in advance:

```
Arrays.sort(num);
Collections.addAll(set, num);
```

The more general solution would be to copy the set to a new collection afterwards and sort that.

If the numbers are in a specific range, especially positive and not sparse, you might use a **BitSet**. That really is a performant solution if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java implementation that does a sorting before returning the iterator. There are only implementations like `TreeSet` that are sorted due to their data structure.

At some point the sorting have to be done. There cannot be a (Hash-)Implementation that supports constant time `adding` and `getting` and being inherently sorted. If something like this would exist then we would be able to sort in constant time.

If you want to stay with a `Hash`-Implementation then you must do the "sorting work" directly before/after retrieving the elements. Since you cannot change the `before` the only solution is to sort `after` retrieving the elements.

Sample code with Guava's Ordering:

```
while (Integer i : Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(hashSet)) {
    // "i" in sorted order
}
```